# Converting int to hex string using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, type-conversion

I'm doing an assignment where I have to convert an integer number to a hexadecimal string using recursion. I have to do this using a method that returns a string value. I tried to turn the method I'm using on paper into code and it works just fine:

```
public class ItH {
private static String intToHex(int n) {
    int temp = n % 16;
    String digit = "";

    if (temp < 10) digit += temp;
    if (temp > 9) {
        switch (temp) {
            case 10: digit="A"; break;
            case 11: digit="B"; break;
            case 12: digit="C"; break;
            case 13: digit="D"; break;
            case 14: digit="E"; break;
            case 15: digit="F"; break;
        }
    }
    if (n > 0) return intToHex((n-temp)/16) + digit;
    return "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(intToHex(1234));
    System.out.println(intToHex(257));
    System.out.println(intToHex(0));
}


}
```

It works just fine for the first two examples used in the main method, but I can't get it to display zero. Is there a way to get it to display zero without modifying too much? I've been going over it for some time now and I can't figure out a way to do that without adding at least one zero before every other number.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes you have special cases where you have to do something besides the "straight" algorithm.  In this case, I'd check the final string before it's returned to the user.  If it's empty, set it to a single "0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
private static String intToHex(int n) {
    int temp = n % 16;
    String digit = "";

    if (temp < 10) digit += temp;
    if (temp > 9) {
        switch (temp) {
            case 10: digit="A"; break;
            case 11: digit="B"; break;
            case 12: digit="C"; break;
            case 13: digit="D"; break;
            case 14: digit="E"; break;
            case 15: digit="F"; break;
        }
    }
    if ( (n-temp)/16 == 0 ) return digit;
    if (n > 0) return intToHex((n-temp)/16) + digit;
    return "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(intToHex(1234));
    System.out.println(intToHex(257));
    System.out.println(intToHex(0));
}
```

Just add in that extra if statement,

```
    if ( (n-temp)/16 == 0 ) return digit;
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have been more specific. I can't just add another variable to the method.

Comment: THANK YOU! I wouldn't have come up with that in a long time.